# How to avoid multiple windows opening on subsequent instances of Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Say I have one instance of Visual Studio running where I have opened few windows like Unit Test Explorer, Resharper TODO explorer and so on and to take advantage of multiple monitors I have moved these windows out of visual studio to different monitors.

Now if I open different  solutions in new instances of Visual studio (say from Visual Studio > Recent items jump lists) all the new instances also open with similar windows  in each instance, even though I don't really need those in those new instances. These clutter my work space and I have hunt and close these one by one.

This continues until I close all the news Visual studio instances, close all the windows on the first one instance I had and close that instance as well.

I understand this behavior stems from the fact that the new instances inherit the opened windows etc. configuration from the first opened instance.

Is there any way to prevent the same windows from opening on subsequent instances of visual studio?

Or may be a configuration to launch visual studio with default windows?

Or quick way to kill all these unwanted windows?

I looked through the VS > Options > Environment > Startup and Tabs and Windows etc., devenv.exe command lines but don't find anything useful.

Comment: Quick way would be to establish your "baseline" window layout, then save that (Window | Save Window Layout). This can then be recalled with Window | Apply Windows Layout | *name* or the assigned shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution provided by @Richard to establish your "baseline" window layout, then save that (`Window | Save Window Layout`) and apply the layout using `Window | Apply Windows Layout | name` or the assigned shortcut helped as a workaround, I see Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 now comes with a preview feature, Autohide tool windows at startup,
that addresses this problem.

[image]

When enabled, any new instances of Visual Studio open only Solution Explorer and not any other windows opened on previous instances. This also improves startup performance noticeably.